What is the meaning of 一部部 in 一部部古汉字经典进入他的资料库?
就这样，一部部古汉字经典进入他的资料库...
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 21. What is the meaning of 一部部? 一部 means some part and 部 is just a classifier?
就这样(so or such)，一部部(?)古汉字(ancient Chinese characters)经典(of Chinese classics)进入(got into)他的(his)资料库(database)...
I think only the 一部部 is unclear to me.

We are talking about the function of [一 + reduplicated classifiers], not unlike this post or this post
一部经典 = a classic
一部部经典 = one classic after another
